# Statistical Significance Issue in Mixed Model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, mixed-model, random-effects-model

A multilevel model, with one explanatory variable at the individual level (X) and one explanatory variable at the group level (Z):

$$Y_{ij}=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{10}X_{ij}+\gamma_{01}Z_{j}+\gamma_{11}X_{ij}Z_{j}+u_{0j}+u_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}$$

correlation between $u_{0j}$ and $u_{1j}$ is $0$ .
In [This pdf](http://joophox.net/publist/methodology05.pdf) , it is written in p.90 that

> The interaction effect of these simulated characteristics are presented in table 4. Tested with a blockwise Bonferroni correction, none of the interactions were statistically significant .

But I found all fixed effect $(\gamma_{00},\gamma_{10},\gamma_{01},\gamma_{11})$ and all random effects $(u_{0j},u_{1j})$ statistically significant except individuals-level residual$(e_{ij})$ .

Now my question is if all of them are insignificant according to the mentioned paper , how can the model be valid ? By indicating all of those insignificant , what do they imply ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks .

#### EDIT :

I found all fixed effect $(\gamma_{00},\gamma_{10},\gamma_{01},\gamma_{11})$ and all random effects $(u_{0j},u_{1j})$ statistically significant according to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166298/testing-fixed-and-random-effect-of-mixed-model) and the codes are copied here :

```
simfun <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1){
     N <- sum(rep(n_j,J))  
     x <- rnorm(N)         
     z <- rnorm(J)         
     mu <- c(0,0)
     sig <- matrix(c(sig2_0,sig01,sig01,sig2_1),ncol=2)
     u   <- MASS::mvrnorm(J,mu=mu,Sigma=sig)

     b_0j <- g00 + g01*z + u[,1]
     b_1j <- g10 + g11*z + u[,2]
      y <- rep(b_0j,each=n_j)+rep(b_1j,each=n_j)*x + rnorm(N,0,sqrt(0.5))
     sim_data <- data.frame(Y=y,X=x,Z=rep(z,each=n_j),group=rep(1:J,each=n_j))
  } 

fit <- function(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1){
    dat <- simfun(J,n_j,g00,g10,g01,g11,sig2_0,sig01,sig2_1)
    full <- lmer(Y~X+Z+X:Z+(X||group),data=dat,control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)))

  #Testing significance of random intercept
  null.U0 <- update(full, .~.-(1 | group))
  dev.U0 <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.U0)))
  p.U0 <- 0.5*(1-pchisq(dev.U0,1))*(1/6) #multiplied by (1/6) since there are 6 parameters to be tested, that is there are 6 null hypothesis.

 #Testing significance of random slope
  null.U1 <- update(full, .~.-(0 + X | group))
  dev.U1 <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.U1)))
  p.U1 <- 0.5*(1-pchisq(dev.U1,1))*(1/6)

 #Testing significance of intercept of fixed part
 null.int <- update(full, .~.-1)
 dev.int <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.int)))
  p.int <- (1-pchisq(dev.U1,1))*(1/6)

 #Testing significance of X of fixed part
 null.x <- update(full, .~.-X)
 dev.x <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.x)))
  p.x <- (1-pchisq(dev.x,1))*(1/6)

#Testing significance of Z of fixed part
 null.z <- update(full, .~.-X)
 dev.z <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.z)))
  p.z <- (1-pchisq(dev.z,1))*(1/6)

#Testing significance of interaction part
 null.xz <- update(full, .~.-X:Z)
 dev.xz <- as.numeric(2*(logLik(full)-logLik(null.xz)))
  p.xz <- (1-pchisq(dev.xz,1))*(1/6)

 pvals <- data.frame(p.U0=p.U0,p.U1=p.U1,p.int=p.int,p.x=p.x,p.z=p.z,p.xz=p.xz)
}

c1 <- replicate(1000,fit(30,5,1,.3,.3,.3,(1/18),0,(1/18)))
colMeans(apply(c1,2,unlist))
```

Comment: "Bu I found all fixed effect (γ 00 ,γ 10 ,γ 01 ,γ 11 )  and all random effects (u 0j ,u 1j )  statistically significant." Maybe you can post how you find this.

Comment: I found them statistically significant according to this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166298/testing-fixed-and-random-effect-of-mixed-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many questions here, some are a bit confusing. But to get started, and answer your previous post, Bonferroni correction is applied *a posteriori*, so that raw p-values for each of the factors are essentially divided by n comparisons (hypotheses). So for the Table 4 example, depending how you define family-wise error rate in the context of this question, and what they meant by "block-wise", it can be by parameter (n=27 comparisons for the 7 parameters) or by parameter-group combination (n=9 for 3 groups sizes) vs. 189 (total number of tests).

Secondly, Table 4 refers to interaction terms, not individual effects themselves, which can still be significant. And perhaps clarification is needed on the response variable, which is "*Noncoverage*" (a type of misclassification indicator) for the 7 regression parameters, not those parameters themselves.

What the quoted statement means is that *Noncoverage* for some of the 7 parameters (fixed and random effects) depends on *Number of Groups* and *Group Size*, but effect of *Number of Groups* does not vary across levels of *Group Size*, and the third factor, *Intraclass Correlation*, which is not significant in any of the interactions or by itself.